# What is the error message corresponding to Bsafe error code?

Tags: c++, openssl

We are using Bsafe cpp code in an application to verify the signature, but it is raising back with error code 540 while calling B_VerifyFinal.

Is it possible to know what this error code corresponds to? and how we will find all the error messages for bsafe error codes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the documentation, or look through the source code for this error number.

Comment: Nothing available from the documentation and I searched for 540 through whole code, but search results also did not show anything. That B_VerifyFinal method may be secured as it deals with keys and certificates

Comment: Corresponding code for B_VerifyFinal is in .lib files

Comment: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-36064/LocalTests/utilLib/bsafeUtils.c?txt This link helped me in finding the error message corresponding to error code. I am able to find hex(540) i.e.0x21c in bsafe.h file, but now dont know what is causing this error